# Error in running shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am just trying to run a simple app in shiny. Below is the code I am using.

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( "sidebar panel"),
    mainPanel("main panel")
  )
))
```

And below is the error I am getting :

```
Listening on http:// 127.0.0.1:4283
ERROR : [On_Request_Read] Connection request by peer.
```

Although my app is running , but this error is also coming out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please show us a server.R part

Comment: Sever.R part is empty.....

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})

Comment: what is your default web browser? It could be a problem if you use Internet explorer

Comment: My default web browser is Chrome.....Also, the results are being opened in the R Studio only, initially it was opening in the browser window ....but I think I have played with display mode